# c# httplistener only catches local ip requests

Tags: c#, networking, get, ip, httplistener

My c# httplistener only catches requests when i send them in the local network (from machines on the same wifi using the local area ip).

When I look my public ip (with "my ip" in google) and type in get requests through that url, i get no responses and my events dont trigger in visual studio

I prefixed it correctly
`listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:2999/");`
and set Access control header, it works perfectly through local url requests, just not public

Also, there are many questions about it not working outside host machine, mine does, just not outside local network because the public ip gets no response

EDIT:
Is there a way to do this without having to do stuff on the router? I'm on a college network and dont have access to router port settings

Comment: What separates your Intranet from the Internet, a router?  Is it configured to route external requests to your host?  Is there a firewall in place between the Internet and Intranet?

Comment: Is there any workaround to sending my computer requests without changing router settings? I'm on a college network and dont have access to that

Comment: The router probably uses [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).  Without configuring it to route traffic specifically to your host, there isn't much you can do.  Unless you happen to be on a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN).

Comment: so is there a way for me to setup a connection between my webserver hosted by godaddy or any other host, and my computer, so that i can go on my site with my phone, press a button and it sends requests to my computer

Comment: With a VPN between systems, e.g. a hosted server and your college PC, you can do quite a bit.  If you have a hosted webserver then you could have your college PC connect to it and ask for work, nothing special is needed to connect outbound from the college to the Internet.  Your smartphone can connect to the hosted server and make requests.

Comment: will it still require special permissions/router access to setup? And also, another option would a dynamic dns service, but I'm guessing that would also require port forwarding/router stuff. Sorry, I dont know too much about networking but the rest of the project hinges on this one simple function...

Comment: @user864572: Dynamic DNS don't help as the requests still need to be forward by the router. The only way is make your college machine make a VPN/tunnel to your server and use that. Note that is is very likely against the college's terms and rules as so you should ask permission first.

Comment: Both your PC and smartphone can connect to a hosted server on the Internet.  If you have an application (or two) on the server that can shuttle information between the clients, e.g. a website for the phone and a web service for the PC, then you may be all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to forward port 2999 from your router's WAN side to your server. This procedure is manufacturer specific and easily searched for on the web.

Comment: Is there any workaround to sending my computer requests without changing router settings? I'm on a college network and dont have access to that

Answer (score 0):

C # HttpListener worked for me (with the correct port forwarding) on the local computer or local network (Windows7). If i access the Internet in response HttpListener always gave an error 50 * may have a ban but I do not know where it is configured.
I had to use TcpListener and manually parse HTTP-requests.